# CMake: path of CXX Compiler in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake, cmake-modules

I am on Windows and I try to compile a C/C++ program using CMake-gui.

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed on my PC.

I set as Windows environment variable for CXX the following path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64

But when I click on 'Configure' in CMake-gui, I get the following error:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at C:/Users/user1/mylibs/cmake-3.22.0-rc1-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CXX:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/user1/mylibs/assimp-master_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/user1/mylibs/assimp-master_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to execute `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat` a batch file that sets all related environment variables.

You can also try opening from the Start menu "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" and executing `vcvarsall.bat` directly.

Comment: When executing this vcvarsall.bat, I get : [ERROR:vcvarsall.bat] Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
Syntax:
    vcvarsall.bat [arch] [platform_type] [winsdk_version] [-vcvars_ver=vc_version] [-vcvars_spectre_libs=spectre_mode]
where :
    [arch]: x86 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_arm | x86_arm64 | amd64_x86 | amd64_arm | amd64_arm64
    [platform_type]: {empty} | store | uwp
    etc...  Any idea ? Thanks

Please make sure either Visual Studio or C++ Build SKU is installed.

Comment: @Regis_AG have you installed the C++ workload?  If not, open the Visual Studio installer and select "Desktop development with C++" workload.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 0):

You should not open cmake-gui by double clicking the icon. You should open a visual studio development command prompt. Then, navigate in the command prompt to the install directory of cmake. Type cmake-gui to start the gui tool. Now it will have the correct environment settings.